# Write to remote file using TCP

Tags: c, networking, network-programming

I am working on a server/client program for a project, for it to be able to work properly I need to use `fopen` and `fprintf` on the client. The server is going to take realtime data output from a USB joystick (the axis rotations) and send that information via TCP to the client which in turn writes that information to a file. I have followed [THIS](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Networking_in_UNIX) tutorial to get the TCP setup and its working perfectly. I am able to send messages from the server to the client. How can I take a command such as `fprintf(fp, "2=%d\n", zAxis)` from the server and send it to the client to be wrote to a file? Maybe I am overlooking something simple to accomplish this. I don't know where to begin, if I can send the `zAxis` variable from the server to the client I think I can figure it out from there.

Here is my code

SERVER.C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define PORTNUM 2343

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char msg1[10];
        printf("Please enter info\n");
        fgets(msg1, 20, stdin);


    struct sockaddr_in dest; /* socket info about the machine connecting to us */
    struct sockaddr_in serv; /* socket info about our server */
    int mysocket;            /* socket used to listen for incoming connections */
    socklen_t socksize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    memset(&serv, 0, sizeof(serv));           /* zero the struct before filling the fields */
    serv.sin_family = AF_INET;                /* set the type of connection to TCP/IP */
    serv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* set our address to any interface */
    serv.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);           /* set the server port number */    

    mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    /* bind serv information to mysocket */
    bind(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

    /* start listening, allowing a queue of up to 1 pending connection */
    listen(mysocket, 1);
    int consocket = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);

    while(consocket)
    {
        printf("Incoming connection from %s - sending welcome\n", inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
        send(consocket, msg1, strlen(msg1), 0); 
        consocket = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);
    }

    close(consocket);
    close(mysocket);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}`
```

CLIENT.C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define MAXRCVLEN 500
#define PORTNUM 2343

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char buffer[MAXRCVLEN + 1]; /* +1 so we can add null terminator */
   int len, mysocket;
   struct sockaddr_in dest; 

   mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));                /* zero the struct */
   dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
   dest.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.254.16"); /* set destination IP number */ 
   dest.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);                /* set destination port number */

   connect(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

   len = recv(mysocket, buffer, MAXRCVLEN, 0);

   /* We have to null terminate the received data ourselves */
   buffer[len] = '\0';

   printf("Received %s (%d bytes).\n", buffer, len);

   close(mysocket);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: From your `fprintf` statement, I'm assuming `zAxis` is an integer. Why can you not send this data? `sprintf(buffer, "%d", zAxis)` and then send `buffer`.

Comment: Also, note that `send` and `recv` need not send/receive the specified number of bytes. Those functions will return the bytes _actually_ sent. So you must loop `send` and `recv` until bytes actually sent = bytes you want to be sent.